# How to test the stripe webhook endpoint from POSTMAN

Tags: node.js, typescript, postman, stripe-payments, aws-serverless

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';




const stripKey = process.env.STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY;
const stripe = new Stripe(stripKey, { apiVersion: '2023-10-16'});

export async function webhook (event) {
  console.log('Received Stripe Event:', event);

    const stripeEndpointKey = process.env.STRIP_ENDPOINT_KEY;
    let stripeEvent;
  
    if (stripeEndpointKey) {
      console.log("inside if stripeEndKey=======>", stripeEndpointKey)
        // Get the signature sent by Stripe
        const signature = event.headers['Stripe-Signature'];
        console.log("signature=========>", signature)
        try {
           stripeEvent = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
            event.rawBody,
            signature,
            stripeEndpointKey
          );
          console.log("stripeEvent-------->", stripeEvent);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`, err.message);
        }
      }
  
      // Handle the specific event type
      switch (stripeEvent.type) {
        
        case 'checkout.session.completed':
          const paymentIntent = stripeEvent.data.object;
         // console.log('Received Stripe Event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

          console.log("pamyentintend====>",paymentIntent);
          console.log("testing the stripe event")
         // await handlePaymentSucceeded(stripeEvent.data.object);
          break;
        // Add more cases for other event types as needed
  
        default:
          console.log(`Unhandled event type: ${stripeEvent.type}`);
      }
  
      return { statusCode: 200, body: 'Webhook handled successfully' };
    }
```

above is my typescipt async function, I am using serverless framework.

I want to test the above endpoint using postman
in the POST method I am passing raw body which is below.

```
{
    "type": "checkout.session.completed",
    "data": {
        "object": {
            "id": "session_id"
        }
    }
}
```

when I hit the API I am getting error in my console like :

Webhook signature verification failed. No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?

I have tested the same endpoint using stripe CLI
I followed below steps to test it from stripe CLI:
stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost:3000/dev/v1/webhook --timeout 120
i added this endpoint to listen
and after that in the another console I used below command:
stripe trigger checkout.session.completed

after that i got response
but when I am trying to test from postman I am getting signature error
please help me to resolve this.
I am trying to create webhook endpoint for the recurring payment.

Comment: The Stripe CLI is built specifically to help you test webhooks, why do you want to test webhook signature verification using Postman? You're only passing in the raw request body, however, the webhook signature is found in the header which you've not mentioned. Doing signature verification via Postman is likely also going to result in issues because of the timestamp used to generate the signature - Stripe libraries will reject the payload if the timestamp is too old : https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#replay-attacks so you'll have to account for that too.

Comment: Okay thanks.
So how can I trigger webhook for the recurring payment.
Using the CLI I can test it locally but in the production how would I check

Comment: When you get to production, you're expected to have already completed testing. You should have registered your production webhook endpoint : https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#register-webhook and when payment is made / completed, you should automatically receive the event